# I have problem with time zone package in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

i try to make a custom notification but i have some error
thats my error :

> Exception has occurred.
>
> LateError (LateInitializationError: Field '_local@263310200' has not
> been initialized.)

and that's my cods :

```
 import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;
import 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;

class NotificationService {
static final NotificationService _notificationService =
   NotificationService._internal();

factory NotificationService() {
return _notificationService;
}

final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

NotificationService._internal();

Future<void> initNotification() async {
final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
    AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/launcher_icon');

final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
    IOSInitializationSettings(
  requestAlertPermission: false,
  requestBadgePermission: false,
  requestSoundPermission: false,
);

final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
    InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
        iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);

await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings);
}

Future<void> showNotification(
  int id, String title, String body, int seconds) async {
return await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
  id,
  title,
  body,
  tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(seconds: seconds)),
  const NotificationDetails(
    android: AndroidNotificationDetails('main_channel', 'Main Channel',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.max,
        icon: '@drawable/launcher_icon'),
    iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(
      sound: 'default.wav',
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    ),
  ),
  uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
      UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
  androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
);
}

Future<void> cancelAllNotifications() async {
await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.cancelAll();
 }
 }
```

also i use thats packages :
flutter_local_notifications: ^9.4.0
timezone: ^0.8.0

i dont know why i have a this errors

Comment: `package:timezone` requires you to perform [an explicit initialization step](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone#initialization), e.g. with `tz.initializeTimeZones();`.  It sounds like you didn't do that.